# Unable to view my login screen and terminal screen

Tags: 12.04, drivers, display-manager

I'm unable to view my login screen and terminal screen - they're fully blank. Using PuTTY tool remote terminal is working, because if I install Wine in my Ubuntu 12.04 after restarting my PC, I'm unable view any screen. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to reconfigure lightdm, it may fix your issue**

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigre lightdm
  ```
- Then chose `lightdm` from the list.
- Restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

It may fix your issue. If doesn't fix then follow first remove **Wine** completely and repeat above step. Since after installing **Wine** you got the issue, removing it may help you. Here are the steps to completely remove wine:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove wine
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo find / | grep wine | grep -v '/var/cache/apt/archives/' | sudo xargs rm -r -f
```